# Web scraping - Distinguishing tags

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on a project called Wikipedia for Blind which reads out the contents of any wikipedia web page. Here I want to somehow distinguish between normal text and hyperlinks. I am aiming to change the sound whenever a hyperlink (a tag in HTML) is encountered. But i have no idea on how to identify what part of the text is a hyperlink. How can i achieve this?

I have used BeautifulSoup library in Python. It has a method called get_text() that extracts all the text from the paragraph and therefore, i am unable to distinguish hyperlink from normal text.

Comment: Let's start by showing us your code, and explaining in detail what works, what doesn't work, what information do you need, and in which format. Please see what a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) means, and also [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

get_text() using BeautifulSoup is not enough, Hyperlinks in HTML are typically represented by the ***a*** tag. I can share an example with you.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'your_url_here'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    hyperlink_text = link.get_text()
    hyperlink_url = link.get('href')
    print(f"Hyperlink Text: {hyperlink_text}")
    print(f"Hyperlink URL: {hyperlink_url}")
    
for paragraph in soup.find_all('p'):
    paragraph_text = paragraph.get_text()
```